# Unexpected behaviour on Stack Overflow site for programmatic click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, reload

While answering one of the Stack Overflow questions, I was running the script in console tab and came across some weird, unexpected behaviour. So the script I am running is simple.

```
$("a").click()
```

So when I run this script in console on Stack Overflow site the site's UI changes (which is understandable), but now if I close the tab, and again open( tried hard refresh too) the Stack Overflow site, still getting this new changed UI, while expected was it should have reset to original UI.

And then again if I run the above script, UI changes to original.

So can anyone explain why is it persisting the changes done through console tab when it is supposed to be there only until refresh?

Note: I understand SO question should not be like *what is the problem* but I think this is bit different, still I can delete if community wants so.

Comment: site doesn't use browser cache for this

Comment: @A.Wolff I didnt understand, browser cache's relation to persisting locally run scripts effect, can you please explain further

Comment: I don't understand it either... :)

Comment: @A.Wolff The site is using the cookies to save some information, And the UI is actually a mobile UI. There is link at bottom to change the UI for mobile view. when script is run again, it's actually triggering that one. I should have got that earlier, feel silly now.

Comment: Site is using some persistent storage data client side (cookie or localStorage). I'm not sure how do you test it nor on which browser. If you effectively clearing the cache (e.g ctrl+shift+del), close all opened browser windows/tab and reopen, you'll get default SO UI (from what i can test). Some data could still persist if you don't close all opened tabs/windows on some browser. Unfortunately, i don't have any documentation to share about it, i'm talking about experience only.

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks for sharing the info. I searched the localStorage, there was nothing related data present there. I tested using Firefox (ctrl+shift+del) with various combination and got that if selected cookies only to delete in (ctrl+shift+del), UI restores, just by refresh, without closing/reopening the tab.

Comment: It is stored in cookie under `theme`. Try in console: `document.cookie.split(";").forEach(function(c) { if(/^theme/.test(c)) document.cookie = c.replace(/^ +/, "").replace(/=.*/, "=;expires=" + new Date().toUTCString() + ";path=/"); });` then refresh page

Comment: @A.Wolff I tried on FF and chrome nothing happened, but you are right, I can see the theme property in cookie.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting , I just logged the element. it shows something like this

```
<a class="topbar-icon js-site-switcher-button icon-site-switcher-bubble">, <a>, <a class="topbar-icon icon-inbox js-inbox-button">, <a class="topbar-icon icon-achievements js-achievements-button">, <a>, <a class="icon-close js-close-button"
```

I suppose that button switches the site and saves the the UI state in cache thats why refreshing also brings up the new UI.

Comment: Nope, its not in Cache. Tried with clearing cache and it still persists untill run again.